# Jmeter- Does not recognize letters from the file

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, I upload users file.csv with 'CSV Data Set Config', I've seen that the jmeter recognize the file but in the request, he didn't recognize the letters. someone know what needs to change? 
enter image description here

Comment: Please add csv configuration and data

Comment: I've used in csv configuration. but the CSV file contains excel and the delimiter that I used  ' , '